# python matplotlib Agg vs. interactive plotting and tight_layout

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

If I use the `Agg` backend, I'm unable to keep image windows open with `show()` (regardless of `block=True` or not)---they just close virtually immediately.  If I don't use `Agg`, then I get the warning:

`/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/tight_layout.py:225: UserWarning: tight_layout : falling back to Agg renderer warnings.warn("tight_layout : falling back to Agg renderer")`

Sample code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')      # With this line = figure disappears; without this line = warning
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
mu, sigma = 0, 0.5
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
plt.plot(x, mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma))
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Is there a different backend or methodology I should be using?

Comment: What is your default backend?  If you do `import matplotlib as mpl` and then `mpl.get_backend()`, whad do you get?  This will be the backend it uses when you don't specify "Agg", and you may be able to get what you want by switching to a different backend from either of those two.

Comment: @zhermes : did you finally find a work around. I am facing the same problem.

Comment: The unsatisfying workaround is to remove `mpl.use('Agg')`, and to use `fig.set_tight_layout(True)` instead of `fig.tight_layout()` as suggested by @FelipeCorreia

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The workaround, given by [@FilipeCorreia in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455029/python-matplotlib-agg-vs-interactive-plotting-and-tight-layout#comment30027722_15456334), is to remove `mpl.use('Agg')`, and use `fig.set_tight_layout(True)` instead of `fig.tight_layout()`.

Comment: Or if using the non-object-oriented interface, `plt.gcf().set_tight_layout(True)` instead of `plt.tight_layout()`.

Comment: @1'' I don't say `plt.tight_layout()`, I use `fig.tight_layout()`... which is *the object* returned by `plt.gcf()`.

Comment: Of course, just including this comment for people who are only familiar with the `plt.function()` syntax.

Answer (score 6):

`Agg` is a [non-interactive backend](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend), meaning it won't display on the screen, only save to files. Which backend are you using? You have OSX, perhaps you can try the 'macosx', or an interactive backend that uses Agg (eg. QT4Agg, WXAgg).

Comment: Thanks Tiago, I tried both of those and I'm still getting the same warning message.  What I don't understand is, if it's 'falling back to AGG', then why does the interactive plotting still work?

Comment: If opt to choose interactive mode you can try `fig.set_tight_layout(True)` instead of `fig.tight_layout()`. See the comments on [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1852) on github.

Comment: @FilipeCorreia Your suggestion works even when using a non-interactive backend other than Agg, like pdf.  Could you post it as an answer?